# Executing script as daemon process in PHP

Tags: php, bash

This script in my php page javascript which is called on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var id =0;
        function getData(){    
        $.ajax({
              url       : "refresh.php",
              type      : "POST",
              data      : {"id" : id},            
              success   : function(data) {
                 $(".show").html(data);
              }
          });
    }
        $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval("getData()",36000);//Polls in every x sec
    });
    </script>
```

`refresh.php` does my actual process, which I want to get executed every 1 hour

What is the way so that `refresh.php` get executed autmatically at everyone hour?

refresh.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $feedUrl = "http://api.frrole.com/v1/curated-content?location=India&contenttype=link&orderby=popularity&apikey=wmqmz15svzH8qSy5yQuF52b068a40a69e";
    $json = file_get_contents($feedUrl);
    $code = json_decode($json,true);

    foreach($code as $arr)
    {
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
    echo $arr[$k]['title']."<br>";
    echo $arr[$k]['city']."<br>";
    //inserts this vvalue in db
    echo "<br>";
    }
    }
```

?>

I have seen all result of `execute php script in background` om Google

which show solution like this:

1. `nohup php myscript.php &`

   but nohup has some issues
  2.

`exec("/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/php /path/to/child.php 2> /dev/null' &");`

and other

I am confused. Which one is correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a script to execute automatically every hour, you might want to investigate cron. Most web hosts offer cron services through their control panel at least.

Answer (score 1):

use `crontab -e` if you are on linux
then enter this for every hour

> 0 * * * * /bin/php /your_path/refresh.php

then save the file

> :wq

Comment: @CHABLIA: if entering manual was permitted then surely there would not have any issue. I want complete automation